# Input constraints in AngularJS / Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constraint-programming

**Background**

This might be a tough question but it's a task that is required a lot in enterprise applications.

Consider a set of inputs:

- slider 1 -> value a
- slider 2 -> value b
- input box 1 -> value c

And a set of input constraints:

- a + 5 >= b
- a + c = 20
- ...

And a set of priorities, for example a has priority over b which is above c. This means that in order to satisfy one constraint the lower priority variable can be adjusted before the higher one.
Bonus points if the priorities can be dynamically assigned based on user input (which control was last touched).

Usually the client is always untrusted so the same validations have to be performed on the web server, requiring a duplicate mess of nested ifs and switch statements.

**Questions**

Is there a framework that allows such constraints to be defined in AngularJS? Since it already has data-binding it seems kind of silly to have a layer in parallel with that instead of leveraging Angular's framework.

Is there any Java (preferable) framework that allows this as well?

*Would be nice if both can take a JSON/JavaScript-like syntax that can specify equations and priorities, in a clear meta-language, without using language-specific constructs.*

Comment: Although this is an intriguing idea I think there's some problems with it.  It assumes you have a UI framework that your using (people use lots of different things, Bootstrap, Foundation, Phonegap, Ionic, etc.) which enforces an interface on the inputs to allow limiting the input or somehow adjusting it (not clear which one should happen).  Also the way you expressed the conditions (a+5>=b) is valid in any C like language (Java, Javascript etc.) and is almost as dense as it can be ("if" is the same number of chars as {}, although I understand the desire to keep it DRY)

Comment: To be honest, you can watch for scope changes in Angular and pass constraint variables as scope variables which would cause the UI to update automatically. There is at least one document describing this if you google for oney_uist2012_constraintjs.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In the end the intermediary solution was to send a makeshift language object to the Javascript UI which then gets parsed into validation rules: Rule("a","b","gt").

This makes future extensions possible and still manages to decouple the client from the server.

There are some solutions available - Casowary and ConstraintJS - which allow something like this to be built but they require a lot of setting up and might not be stable enough.

Note:
I'm surprised that the interest in this was actually negative and I could jump to conclusions and say that everyone either: a) hardcodes their constraints or b) writes a custom solution. Having seen my fair share of code I'm more inclined towards a).